# How to load template in i frame with in another template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a archive template in which I want to try add other template in `iframe` but I don't know how to add this? I am trying to do like this one

`<iframe id="iframeBox" src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();?>/archive-programmes.php' sandbox="" FRAMEBORDER="no" height="500" width="500"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

I would create a page using that template and use the page URL on to your iframe.

```
<iframe id="iframeBox" src='URL here' sandbox="" FRAMEBORDER="no" height="500" width="500"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

@seema,

Not sure what you are trying to achieve here but you can do such a thing using `get_template_part` function. Alternatively if you only want to use iframe then you will have to include the page created using the template and not the template file itself.